# GraphQL error: Variable $customerAccessToken of type String! was provided invalid value

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm attempting to recover a customer using the customerAccessToken that is given when the user logs in to Shopify.

Using Apollo, here's my code:

```js
this.apollo.mutate({
  mutation: getCustomerFromToken,
  variables: {
    input: {
      customerAccessToken: '217b9a6952c28eb4db376487a6301294' // Also tried btoa('217b9a6952c28eb4db376487a6301294')
    }
  },
})
```

Here's my GraphQL query:

```js
query getCustomerFromToken($customerAccessToken: String!) {
  customer(customerAccessToken: $customerAccessToken) {
    id
    addresses(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
        address1
        address2
        company
        city
        province
        zip
        country
        phone
        }
      }
    }
    orders(first: 200) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          id
          totalPriceV2 {
            amount
            currencyCode
          }
          processedAt
          orderNumber
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here's the login GraphQL code I'm using to retrieve the accessToken from Shopify:

```js
mutation customerAccessTokenCreate($input: CustomerAccessTokenCreateInput!) {
  customerAccessTokenCreate(input: $input) {
    customerAccessToken {
      accessToken
      expiresAt
    }
    customerUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was two fold.

1. I was using a mutation on a query end point
2. Queries don't use input in the payload

```js
const payload = {
    customerAccessToken: "..."
}

// NOT

const payload = {
  input: {
    customerAccessToken: "..."
  }
}
```